# Wallpaper change

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.  My problem is when I select a desktop background, the desktop doesn't update with the new wallpaper.  I am unaware of what might be the error.  For more clarification look at the image.

EDIT:What ever the wallpaper i have selected now , thats applying as wallpaper after a restart and one more thing is i can add wallpapers but what ever i have selected they are not applying as wallpaper .

[image]

Comment: this used to happen to me in 10.10 when both the old and the new wallpapers were in same folder _in my windows NTFS drive._

Comment: @Piyush Kumar  , Thank you . so from your words i can get one solution that keeping  wallpapers in Home dir is better but i want to make it from NTFS .

Comment: I had to delete the entry (in right pane) to get that working..

Comment: No my issue seems to be different , Ubuntu will have some default wallpapers , so they also not applying .

Comment: sorry, no idea about that.. can changing wallpaper from terminal help? (maybe it'll report some errors) http://superuser.com/questions/258568/changing-ubuntu-wallpaper-using-terminal-or-from-command-line

Comment: KDE occasionally does this when wallpaper cache files don't get updated.  I'm not sure if something like that exists or where it might be for Unity though.  For kde it's in the ~/.kde[4] directory.

Comment: i hope there will be a solution for unity also .

Comment: Does this still happen? I think this looks like a bug as it's not the expected behavior.

Comment: But I'm still experiencing this. but I can have the change in kde & not in unity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you hit the plus sign and add your own documents?

I did this and it works ok for me:

[image]

Comment: What ever the wallpaper i have selected now , thats applying as wallpaper after a restart